# get the exact path in associated textbox in file upload contoller in asp

Tags: .net

I am using `ASP` file upload controller.. when i upload files in that, i get path in associated text box of file upload controller as `C:\Users\owner\Desktop\ima6.jpg`.

But when i access that path in code behind file iam getting a default path
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ima6.jpg`

But i want that actual path listed in associated textbox of fileupload controller. then i want to store that file in ftp server...

so any one help me... for this task... iam using `visualstudio2008`,language is 
C# and the browser is mozilla

Comment: for security reasons the browser only sends your the filename without any path information... so: no, what you want is not possible with HTML/JS... you would have to use ActiveX, Java Applet or similar on the client side...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the exact path, you have to save the file like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string filePath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
filePath += "temp-folder/";
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    filePath += FileUpload1.FileName;
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response ... but it is a web appn. so the client has the right to upload the files from their system. if the system doesn't contain the folder "temp_folder" then what can we do?///////..

Comment: Once the file is uploaded you'll have to save them somewhere.. "temp_folder" it's just a sample.

Comment: but when running ,, a error is listed "file could not be find in specified position